# Complex Math- Programming question

Tags: algorithms

You have a matrix of N rows and M columns. 
There are 3 possible outcomes in every position.
A) There can be a dot, which means that you can go on this position
B) There can be a plus sign (+) , which means you went to see an autoshow
C) There can be a ladder sign, which represents the not available position to proceed in.

Something like this : http://prntscr.com/8d2zrl

You start from position 1,1 (upper left corner) and your goal is to went to most possible autoshows (plus signs) by going to position N, M (lower right corner, which is a Pit-stop (a turnaround) to return back to position 1,1.

Something like this : http://prntscr.com/8d31go

The solution should work for every given matrix of any dimensions.

When you are going from position 1,1 to position N,M you can only go down or right, and when you are going back (from position N,M to position 1,1) you can only go up or left. On the way back you are allowed to reuse positions you used on the way down, but there is no additional reward (autoshow) if you picked it up previously. You can assume that it will always be possible to reach (N,M) from (1,1) (and hence to get back).

Comment: Any restrictions on the way back to $(1, 1)$? Can it just be the way there, mirrored?

Comment: Surely you understand no solution will work for any given dimensions. What about $M = N = 10^{10^{500}}$? Give some actual expected upper bounds.

Comment: 100 < M & N < 2 (M& N can be different)

restrictions are same as going to M,N position, not "touching" the ladder sign.

Comment: Also, this problem seems more programming-related than math-related to me. You can check that there are [${(M-1)+(N-1) \choose M-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) paths, ignoring `#` signs: every path must make $(M-1)+(N-1)$ steps, of which $M-1$ must go right, and you get to choose when to take those steps in your sequence

Comment: I realized that part, but after that I stuck.

Comment: Without some additional assumptions there is no way to guarantee you will ever get to (N,M). First, it is tacitly assumed that (1,1) is reachable, i.e., is not '#'. Second, if the two squares adjacent to it ( (1,2) and (2,1) ) are both '#', you have no legal moves at all. How are you going to get to (3,3) (say)?

Comment: Additional info : You will always have at least one "good" path to Pit-stop (N,M).

Comment: @CuriousMe: Am I to take it from your last answer that Mauris' first question is answered in the affirmative? That is, if there may be just the one "good" path, you must be allowed to retrace your steps on the way back.

Comment: Yes, if there is only one good path, then you must be allowed to just come back that way.

Comment: I feel like some kind of pathfinding algorithm on a graph made from the right/down moves with a higher utility assigned to the nodes containing a `+` will suffice. But this really isn't a Math.SE question IMO.

Comment: I thought there is some Math/Logic answer to this problem, but I guess I was wrong. :)

Comment: OK. What happens to the autoshows on that one path? Do you get to count them twice?  And what if there are two "good" paths? Can you retrace your steps then, or are you forced to use a different route? (How different does it have to be? --- e.g., cannot use any field more than once unless absolutely necessary.)

Comment: @Mauris: If the rules can be formulated unambiguously, the problem has an integer programming formulation, and I believe it is NP-hard. This would, I think, make it admissible here.

Comment: When you see autoshow (+ sign) it transforms into a dot (passable position). So you count them once. 
It is obligatory to see maximum number of autoshows possible.

Comment: Do `+` signs you pass on the way back count if you *didn't* already pass them on the way there?

Comment: @Mauris : Yes, they count.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to find the highest score there; delete the shows you have seen; and then find the highest score back.  This may not be the highest two-way score.
The rest of this answer is for a one-way score.
Each square has two possible in-doors, from $(x-1,y)$ and $(x,y-1)$ and two possible out-doors.  Some squares have only one in-door or only one out-door.
For each square, choose the in-door with the higher count-so-far.  Then, from $(N,M)$, you know which in-door you should have entered from; and (while still talking about the first trip) trace back towards $(1,1)$, to find which path gives the greatest sum from $(1,1)$ to $(N,M)$.
It works a little like Pascal's Triangle, except that, instead of each number being the sum of two previous values, it is the maximum of two previous values (or the maximum +1 if the square has a +)

Comment: I like this answer, makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer can be extended to the whole tour, using the idea that any path from (1,1) to (N,M) to (1,1) can be reversed. (The reversal caters to the updating necessary when you pick up a reward and update the square it is on.) But it needs to be extended a bit, because at the start there are no previous values. You calculate those as you go.

Here is how it works, by stepping the path backwards. There are (at most) two squares from which you can reach (1,1): (1,2) and (2,1). Both of them pick up any reward at (1,1). So which one you pick is immaterial (so far).

At the next layer, there are (at most) three squares at a distance of 2 from (1,1): (1,3) --- in which case you must go to (1,2) and pick up any reward there; (3,1) --- going to (2,1) and picking up the reward at (2,1); (2,2) --- in which case you have the choice of going to (1,2) or (2,1). Pick the one with the larger reward and make a record of which way you went, as well as the remaining rewards at each node.

At the next layer, there are four squares a distance of 3 from (1,1): (1,4), (2,3), (3,2) and (4,1). From (4,1) you can only go to (3,1), adding the reward at (3,1) to the additional rewards you can pick up when moving from (3,1) to (1,1). Similarly you treat (1,4). From (3,2) and (2,3) you have two choices. Pick the one with the larger reward (including what you pick up at the next step --- (3,1) or (2,2) from (3,2), (2,2) or (1,3) from (2,3). Continue this idea until you reach (N,M). Update the rewards fro the way back to (1,1) and repeat the procedure from (N,M) back to (1,1). Once you have the complete path, reverse the steps, as stated at the outset.